# How can I properly import a Component into my Navigator in React Native?

Tags: javascript, import, reactjs, module, react-native

I have a component named `EnterName` in another folder I want to use in my `Navigator` in my `index.ios` file. When I put `EnterName` in the same file I get no problems, but when I try and import it from another file I get:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components 
or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. 
Check the render method of `Navigator`
```

I've tried two different ways of importing the EnterName component, and neither work:

`import {EnterName} from './App/Components/EnterName';
var EnterName = require('./App/Components/EnterName');`

Below is some text that uses `Navigator` and tries to use the component `EnterName` from another folder (this works when EnterName is declared in the same file).

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        initialRoute={{name: 'Name entry', index: 0}}
        renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
            <EnterName
              name={route.name}
              onForward={() => {
                var nextIndex = route.index + 1;
                navigator.push({
                  name: 'Scene ' + nextIndex,
                  index: nextIndex,
                });
              }}
              onBack={() => {
                if (route.index > 0) {
                  navigator.pop();
                }
              }}
            />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

And, if you want to see the EnterName file, it's here:

```
import React, {
  Text,
  View,
  Component,
  Image,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

class EnterName extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.center}>
        <View style={styles.flowRight}>
          <TextInput style={styles.inputName}
            placeholder="Enter your name"
            textAlign="center"
            onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
            //value={this.state.text}
          />

          <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
          underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Go </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </View>
      )
  }
}
// The stylesheet is here, and then below it I have:
module.export = EnterName;
```

Can you help me figure out how to modularize my code?

**EDIT: I just forgot the "s" at the end of module.exports. Seems like export default class _classname extends Component { is the way to go.**

Comment: Try doing `export default class EnterName extends Component`

Comment: I tried that both with and without the `module.export = EnterName`, and then with both of my variations of importing in the index.ios class. Did not work.

Comment: You can refer to https://github.com/react-native-simple-router-community/react-native-simple-router

Comment: I always use `module.exports = EnterName`, I don't know much about JavaScript and what's valid, but could that be the issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you missed 's' at the end of `module.export`.  It should be `module.exports`.  In that case the import should be

```
import EnterName from './App/Components/EnterName
```

Instead of module.exports you can also use

```
export default class EnterName extends Component
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import